# Fix maximum number of threads for a program using a Mutex or Semaphor

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

Just a heads up this project is for a school and I am very new to both C and multithreading.

I am attempting to run a statistical analysis function on every unordered pair of files from an input list using multiple threads. I am required to accept an input from the user for the number of threads running.

The way I currently have my program set up, I have already created an array of structs which contain the file names for each comparison that has to be made like so:

```
typedef struct JSD {
    float distance;
    char * name1;
    char * name2;
    int w_cnt;
};
```

I was thinking that rather than having to create a separate queue structure to hold a list of all comparisons, I could simply iterate over the entire array creating a thread for each element and then outputting the results back into the array. My belief is that with this approach I do not have to protect the array struct like I would a queue because each thread will only be working on a singular element at a time. I am aware that thread creation is cpu intensive process but that really isn't a major concern for me currently.

However, I am not sure how to prevent additional thread instances if I already have reached the predefined thread limit while continuing to iterate through my array. My thought was to create a variable to keep track of the current number of threads running but that number obviously needs to have its access restricted to prevent a race condition. I was wondering if a mutex or semaphore would be able to accomplish this.

Will either of these be able to achieve my what I am trying to do? I am not really familiar with each, so if they will work any guidance in setting one up would be appreciated. Or am I wrong about not needed to protect my array and I should just make a queue.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it would be to keep a count of how many threads you have launched so far, and once your count reaches (your maximum-threads value), call `pthread_join()` on the first thread you created.  `pthread_join()` won't return until that thread has exited, so your main thread won't continue (or launch any more child threads) until the first/oldest thread has finished.

After `pthread_join()` has returned, you can launch another thread, then call `pthread_join()` on the second thread you created, then launch another thread, then call `pthread_join()` on the third thread, and so on until you've reached the end of the array (and at that point you should also call `pthread_join()` on all the remaining threads, just to make sure they have all run to completion before your program exits)

Comment: Would this implementation require a mutex? Do I avoid a runoff condition by waiting for pthread_join to decrement?

Comment: No mutex is required by this implementation (well, `pthread_join()` probably uses a mutex internally somewhere, but you don't interact with it directly).  `phread_join()` merely blocks the main thread to keep it from launching more threads before any of the initial N threads have completed their work.  The only race condition it avoids is the race condition where (if you never call pthread_join()) your main() might return (and therefore cause the entire process to exit) while some child threads are still executing, causing some of the threads to be killed before they can finish.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jeremy. Although I am still a bit confused on catching a specific thread. I initialized an array for holding a number of threads, but I am not sure if that is compatible with the structure you suggested.

Comment: @sbling I assume you are spawning your threads using `pthread_create()` or similar; if so, then the first argument to `pthread_create` is a pointer to a `pthread_t` object that `pthread_create()` overwrites to contain a unique identifier for the created thread.  Later on, when you want to wait for that thread to exit, you'll want to pass that `pthread_t` value in as the first argument to `pthread_join()`, to tell `pthread_join()` which thread you want to wait for.  (One easy way to store that info would be to add a `pthread_t` member-value to each element of your array)

Answer (score 0):

Here you're describing a [Thread Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) -- workers that will operate independently, but have a maximum number of instances.

There are a couple of approaches.  One is to create the defined number of worker threads at the beginning of the process, and use a controller to distribute work to worker threads as they are available in the pool, and then returns completed threads to a ready state to accept future work.

This is the most flexible approach, I think, because you can build, test and monitor the controller separately from the thread work implementations. If the nature of the work changes, no big deal to the controller.

There's also no real critical section, because the thread state (e.g. ready, working, finished) manages that, and is atomic from the point of view of the controller.

I'm not even interested in the better efficiency of this approach -- it's just easier to maintain.

Comment: I understand that for real world applications a thread pool will be much easier to work with. However, I was wondering if in this particular instance a simple counter would suffice without the need to create a queue perhaps like Jeremy mentioned.

Comment: Jeremy's suggestion is a very naive thread pool.